# MySQL Not Accepting Date Format For Some Dates

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

FYI - I'm still a database newbie.  That said, One of my MySQL tables has a column called "FirstDetect"

[image]

This column houses dates and times in the following format "2017-31-08 14:30:05". I'm importing a CSV file and everything is working just fine. However, some of the dates are not being accepted and the date value is reverted to 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

I assume it has something to do with the field settings. I can manually type this date (**2017-05-09 00:17:42**) into a field under the FirstDetect column, save the results and that date is written to that field as expected.

However, when I try to manually type this date (**2017-31-08 14:30:05**) into a field under the FirstDetect column, save the results, it reverts back to 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Anyone know what's going on here?

I'm using MySQL version 5.5.57

Comment: MySQL dates are in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. `2017-31-08` is not valid, because there's no month `31`. You need to use `STR_TO_DATE` to parse dates in a different format.

Comment: I think I just figured out my own issue. It looks like my format is YYYY-DD-MM and the correct format should be YYYY-MM-DD. Let me test this.

Comment: @Barmar I just realized that. Thanks man. I've been pulling my hair out! ALL DAY!

Comment: Hi. For the future (if not now): [This.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Also [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default format that datetime field uses is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. If you're trying to enter your dates in YYYY-DD-MM format, it's not going to work and it's probably going to be reverted as you described.

You can learn more from the link below.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html